# $\displaystyle L=\lim_{x\to 4}\left(4-\dfrac x2\right)$: find $\delta\gt0$ such that $\left|f(x)-L\right|\lt0.01$ whenever $0\lt|x-4|\lt\delta$.

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find $L$, where $\displaystyle L=\lim_{x\to 4}\left(4-\dfrac x2\right)$
>
> Then find $\delta\gt0$ such that $\left|f(x)-L\right|\lt0.01$ whenever $0\lt|x-4|\lt\delta$.

$L$ is easy to find, but the second question what method should I use?

Answer (score 1):

You need to estimate $| (4 - \frac{x}{2}) - L | = |4 - \frac{x}{2} - 2| = |2 - \frac{x}{2}| = | \frac{4 - x}{2} | = \frac{|x-4|}{2} $

$$ \frac{|x-4|}{2} <\frac{\delta}{2} $$

Now, $\frac{\delta}{2} = 0.01 \iff \delta = 0.02 $